# How to enable adding bookmarks in android webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

I am creating a browser app for android and I want know is there any code that helps to enable adding bookmarks in android webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you will have to add yourself, a `WebView` literally just displays html content. It doesn't come with all features like for example Chrome.

To add/save bookmarks you would need to implement a UI for showing the bookmarking button, for entering the URL, for showing a list of previously bookmarked pages etc. Once you have all that you can then get the `WebView`s current URL by:

```
webView.getUrl();
```

and save that to your database.

Then you have the work of displaying a list of saved bookmarks and allowing the users to click them and have the `WebView` navigate to them.

Here is an example I found (by a simple Google) to help you get started which shows adding a simple bookmarking feature on an `WebView`: https://www.journaldev.com/15729/android-webview-bookmarks

Comment: No problem @Jamal. Always give things a quick Google you will be surprised what turns up sometimes.